# Spring LDAP Base Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ldap, jndi

I have directory structure as

```
ou=studentBase,dc=example,dc=com
```

In my security XML I have

```
<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
  <property name="base" value="ou=studentBase,dc=example,dc=com" />
  <property name="url" value="ldaps://serveraddress:port" />
  <property name="userDn" value="username" />
  <property name="password" value="pwd" />
</bean>
```

I am suppose to query attributes for the container object

```
cn=container,cn=schema,cn=configuration,dc=example,dc=com
```

When I search with base set to

```
cn=container,cn=schema,cn=configuration,dc=example,dc=com

ldapTemplate.search(base, filter.encode(), new AttributesMapper()){
}
```

I get an error

```
org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100238, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of: 'ou=studentBase,dc=example,dc=com']; nested exception is
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100238, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
    'ou=studentBase,dc=example,dc=com']; remaining name cn=container,cn=schema,cn=configuration,dc=example,dc=com
```

Problem is I cannot change the base to search anything other than the base I put in xml configuration file. I tried `SearchControls` as well and had the same issue. How can I search on different base. I have written the whole application and cannot turn around on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another `contextSource` for configuration lookups:

```
<bean id="schemaContextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
  <property name="base" value="cn=configuration,dc=example,dc=com" />
  <property name="url" value="ldaps://serveraddress:port" />
  <property name="userDn" value="username" />
  <property name="password" value="pwd" />
</bean>
```

and make sure that the `userDN` you use has permission to view/alter the online configuration, which should *not* be the same user as for `contextSource`, for security reasons.

But I find it very strange that an application should want to do this.